# How to Execute a Postgres function from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have created a simple nodeJS script and wanted to insert a few records to Postgres DB, how do I execute a Postgres function from NodeJS script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [pg-promise](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise), you can try this:

```js
await db.func('funcName', ['arg1','arg2']);
```

Another way:

```js
await db.any('select * from funcName($1, $2)', [arg1,'arg2']);
```

And for stored procedures:

```js
await db.proc('procName', ['arg1','arg2']);
```

See API: [func](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.func) and [proc](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.proc).